# How to change default arguments in c++

Tags: c++, arguments, default

I know there an answer in following page,but i can't open it in my country...
so, someone kind enough to copy and paste it here.
Thanks in advance

http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/07/changing-c-function-default-arguments.html

Comment: I sympathize, but this isn't what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: @Beta Although consequently this page ranks higher than the linked, so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copy of http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/07/changing-c-function-default-arguments.html**

In C++, default arguments of global scope functions can be changed easily.

Typically we use a constant expression as a default argument. C++ supports static variables as well as a constant expression for a default argument. We can also redeclare a function signature in a new scope with a different default value.

Default arguments are implemented as global static variables. Therefore, same effect can be achieved if we assign a differnt value to the static varibale. Following code shows this interesting feature.

---

```
#include
#include
#include

static int para=200;

void g(int x=para); // default argument is a static variable.
void f(int x=7); // default argument implemented in terms of some static varible.

int main(void)
{
void f(int x=70); // redeclaring function ::f

f(); // prints f70

g(); // prints g200
para=500;
g(); // prints g500

{
void f(int x=700); // redeclaring function f
f(); // prints f700
::g(); // prints g500
}

::f(); // prints f7 !!!!
// Note that earlier f() call in the same scope gave us f70!!
// This shows that :: (scope resolution operator) forces compiler to
// use global declaration with global signature's default value.

{
void g(int x=100); // redeclaring function g
g(); // prints g100!!!
std::cout << "para = " << para << std::endl; // prints para = 500
// Note that though value of para is unchaged local scope
// changes value of default argument.
}
::g(); // prints g500
return 0;
}

void f(int x)
{
std::cout << "f" << x << std::endl;
}

void g(int x)
{
std::cout << "g" << x << std::endl;
}
```

---

As a programming guideline, if you need to change the value of default argument, either by redelcaring the function signature or reassignment of static variable, you better not make it a default argument and keep it a simple argument.

Comment: For completeness, the expression used as a default value can also be a function call. It can pretty much be an arbitrary expression, the limits are mainly that certain variables are off-limits (for example, locals, other parameters to the function, the `this` keyword cannot be used in the expression).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not allowed to copy blog entries verbatim like this (especially without citing your source: I don't think Sumant Tambe, the original author, would appreciate).

Comment: @Luc Touraille, I believe you are right! Thanks for comment. I've added copyright.

Comment: sorry,i know it's not stackoverflow for. but i'm in China. Blogspot.com is block by our government. i don't known why.. i had bought a VPN account some months ago,so i can read blogspot,but it is also banned recently. I have no idea what i can do. even cache of blogspot on google is block by The Great Firewall in China...

Answer (score 0):

The gist of it:

1) Set up a `static`, non-`const` variable.

2) Set the argument to default to that variable's value.

3) Change the variable's value.